# Does $\zeta(s)=\prod \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ converge for $ \Re(s) >1$ for $p= iq $ (Gaussian prime)?what about $\zeta(2),\zeta(4),\cdots$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, gaussian-integers, euler-product

The Riemann zeta function is defined by the Euler product as :$\zeta(s)=\prod \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ it is converge for $ \Re(s) >1$ , now if we plug instead of ordinary prime $p$ the [Gaussian prime](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianPrime.html) of the form $p =i q$ such that $|q|$ is ordinary prime and $|q|=3\bmod 4$ , Now do we still have the product converge for $ \Re(s) >1$,In particular $s = 2n$? For example what about $\zeta(2),\zeta(4),\cdots$?

Clarification: for $s=2$ the product becomes
$\frac{1}{(1+3^{-2})(1+7^{-2})(1+11^{-2})\cdots}$ but this is not $\zeta(2)$.

Comment: $2$ is not a Gaussian prime. Do you know what the Gaussian primes are?

Comment: Thanks , I have edited that , yes 2 is not Gaussian prime , I have montioned now 3 and 7 and 11

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I took the form i q with q  = 3 mod 4

Comment: it seems the downvoter see that is a trivial question

Comment: Do you know about Dirichlet $L$-functions? This should be like an $L$-function with a quadratic character.

Comment: So have you looked up $L$-functions?

Comment: yes you are right , I didn't know this before look $$L(s) = \prod_p\frac{1}{1-g_pp^{-s}}$$
with
$$g_p = \begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{if $p = 2$}\\
\sqrt p & \mbox{if $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$}\\
i\sqrt p & \mbox{if $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score -1):

The convergence of the Riemann zeta-function
is related to that of the geometric series
\[
(1 - x)^{-1} = 1 + x^{2} + x^{3} + \cdots.
\]

Remember that the geometric series
\[
(1 - x)^{-1} = 1 + x^{2} + x^{3} + \cdots
\]
converges absolutely for $|x| < 1$.

And, if $s = a + bi$, then 
\[
|(iq)^{-s}| = |(e^{\pi i /2}q)^{-a - bi}|
= q^{-a}e^{\pi b /2}
\]
and so, for the geometric series of $[1 - (iq)^{-s}]^{-1}$ to converge
absolutely, we need to have
\[
q^{-a}e^{\pi b /2} < 1
\]
for all sufficiently large $q$ primes.

Yes, your zeta-like infinite product converges to whatever it is. But
I don't know if it's useful or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , then what about values of zeta(2),zeta(4) in this case ?

Comment: As I said, I just don't know about it. Some guys out there are interested in the distribution of primes, and the original zeta-function has seemed to satisfy that need.

Comment: The motivation of this question is to know more about connection of Riemann zeta function to Gaussian primes

Comment: Then, it's way over my head.

Comment: How do you get from a geometric series converging to an infinite product converging, soz?

Comment: Are you still here, soz?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson If you were,  recall $\prod_{p \leq x} (1 - p^{-s})^{-1} = \sum_{n, p|n, p\leq x}n^{-s}$.